# console.log prints ObjectId("string")

Tags: javascript, mongodb, console.log, objectid

In Mongo, I can see my object like this

```
_id: ObjectId("5d23f0c37d128545a85a139b")
```

When debugging, I do `console.log` my object, and it prints out:

```
_id: "5d23f0c37d128545a85a139b"
```

Is there a way to print out an actual `ObjectId`, not a string?

Comment: so, you want `ObjectId("5d23f0c37d128545a85a139b")` instead of `"5d23f0c37d128545a85a139b"` in the console?

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectId('an_id')` is one row of a Table

If you use `mongoose`, you can use `populate('id')` and your object will same this:

```
_id: {
    _id: 'abc',
    other_prop: 'prop'
},
...
```

_id is object instead of string.